# Plot network using cosine similarities

Tags: python, networking, graph, cosine-similarity

I have a matrix of `(2544, 2544)` of cosine similarities. I wish to use these to plot a network displaying the connections between them. How can I do this?

I understand I can do this somehow using Gelphi. They accept a [CSV file as input](https://gephi.org/users/supported-graph-formats/csv-format/) however I am unsure how to create the desired input.